# background color using html n css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iteration

I'm trying to loop through a table to get each TD value. If the value is below a specific number then I'll do something.

```
     </head>
     <body>
     <table id="tableData" name="tableData">
     <tr>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>abcd</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>aaaa</td>
     <td>15</td>
     <td>bbbb</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>ccc</td>
     <td>25</td>
     <td>dddd</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </body>
```

above is my code .. i need to change the background colors of the 2nd column as below  . if the value of the 2nd column element is <= 10 then the color is green , from 11-20 its yellow and above 21 its red.
I have given the sample code here. actually in real , the table is derived from the database , iy may have any nomber of rows. so i need to color the column as the page gets loaded.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: But where is your actual `code...`?

Comment: Id's should be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the updated question. Could you change the `id="xxx"` to a more representative value please? As @Zenith states, `id` values must be unique. If those are your actual `id`s then that is your problem.

Comment: thanks !!! then should i do to color that specific column as i needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modified plain JavaScript will colour the `<td>` elements as required:

```
function checkForm() {
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td[id]');

    for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        var i = tds[j].innerHTML;

        if(i < 10){
            tds[j].style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
        } else if(i >= 11 && i <= 20){
            tds[j].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; 
        } else if(i > 20){
            tds[j].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    }
}
```

but you will need to modify the HTML to give the `<td>`s unique ID values, for example

```
<body onload="checkForm();">
    <table id="tableData" name="tableData">
        <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td id="a">5</td>
            <td>abcd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td id="b">15</td>
            <td>bbbb</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ccc</td>
            <td id="c">25</td>
            <td>dddd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

If it is *always* the middle cell that needs colour you could remove the `id`s completely and rely on the fact that is is "always the middle cell". For example use the following selector instead:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)');
```

The only limitation is that [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) is that it is not supported by IE<9. All other browsers support it.

Since the cell that requires a `background-color` is always the 2nd cell, you can use the CSS nth-child selector as the argument to in `querySelectorAll()` to "select the 2nd `<td>` child element of the parent", which in this case is the `<tr>`.

So `td:nth-child(2)` finds the the `<td>two</td>` element for the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
</tr>
```

See [some examples](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/) of how `:nth-child` works.

[**Demo of `id`-less solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pDP4/) (for if the cell to colour is *always* the middle one).

Since OP is stuck with IE8 and IE8 does not support `:nth-child` an alternative [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) can be used to target the 2<sup>nd</sup> child with the caveats that there must only be 3 `<td>` and the 3<sup>rd</sup> must not contain any numbers.

---

**Update:**

Based on the **actual** requirements of needing to work in IE8 and add `background-color` to the 6<sup>th</sup> column, here is a simpler (to read) and more cross-browser compatible jQuery solution:

[**jsBin demo**](http://jsbin.com/uhumak/1/edit) (so it works on IE8)

**HTML**

Remove the `onload="checkForm();` from `<body>`

```
<table id="tableData" name="tableData">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>abcd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>dddd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    var tds = $('td:nth-child(6)');

    for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        var i = tds[j].innerHTML;

        if(i < 10){
            tds[j].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else if(i >= 11 && i <= 20){
            tds[j].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        } else if(i > 20){
            tds[j].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't my demo do what you want? It colours the 2nd column based on the value of the cell.

Comment: hi .. im not the getting the answer . if i use the code var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)'); .

Comment: wat is meant my td:nth-child(3) . can u explain it clearly pls

Comment: Does the demo work for you? I'll update my answer to explain the CSS selector.

Comment: Also, you need the `2`nd child, not the `3`rd. So it's `td:nth-child(2)` and **not** `td:nth-child(3)`

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: actually im working with the eclipse IDE. not in browsers. and my browser is IE8 , it doesnt work there too

Comment: Yes, I did say in my answer it does not work in IE8, as IE8 does not support `:nth-child` selector. I'll try to think of another approach.

Comment: You could use `var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td + td');` instead but only if 1) there are always 3 columns and 2) the 3rd column does not contain numbers.

Comment: actually i have 8 columns . and 6 th column is the one i should color. then how can i give it ?

Comment: Use the jQuery solution I've added in my answer, it's the simplest way to use modern selectors in ancient browsers!

Comment: Use `var tds = $('td:nth-child(6)');` instead - see **Update** in my answer.

Comment: sorry i am still not getting the answer. is there any other way i can color the cells using the column name ??

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use the same ID's for any elements on a page. It is a unique identifier. If you want to reference more than one element, then use a class instead.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is using two classes - one to define xxx, and then one to define its status (colour). Also, if you use semantic naming (instead of .green,.yellow,.red) you will get good understanding of your code.

ex

```
.xxx{ font-weight: bold;}
.less10 { background: green;}
.between1120 {background: yellow; }
.over21 { background: red; }
```

You cannot set CSS depending on the content inside the element. For this you would need some simple jQuery/javascript or your chosen programming language to loop through all the xxx-classes in the table, and add the status class accordingly.

ex

```
<td class="xxx less10">5</td>
<td class="xxx between1120">15</td>
<td class="xxx over21">35</td>
```

Comment: actually i am not getting u . il take of that id's. and my ll be like below <tr>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>abcd</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>aaaa</td>
     <td>15</td>
     <td>bbbb</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>ccc</td>
     <td>25</td>
     <td>dddd</td>
     </tr>
what shld i do to color the specific column .. u know the table actually a contains lots of values . it ll be retreived dynamically from database. so i needed to color accordingly as the page gets loaded itself. PLease help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should change the ID xxx to Class xxx.

```
 function checkForm(){
    $('td.xxx').each(function(){
        var val=parseInt($(this).text());
        if(val<=10) $(this).css({background:'green'});
        else if(val>10 && val<=20) $(this).css({background:'yellow'});
        else if(val>20) $(this).css({background:'red'});
    }
 }
```

I think that should work with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want :
[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sb2BX/25/)`</>`

```
 <table id="tableData" name="tableData">
    <tr>
        <td>
            abc
        </td>
        <td class="xxx">
            5
        </td>
        <td>
            abcd
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            aaaa
        </td>
        <td class="xxx">
            15
        </td>
        <td>
            bbbb
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ccc
        </td>
        <td class="xxx">
            25
        </td>
        <td>
            dddd
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var arr = $(".xxx").toArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (parseInt(arr[i].innerText) < 10) {
                $(arr[i])[0].bgColor = "green";
            }

            else if (parseInt(arr[i].innerText) >= 11 && parseInt(arr[i].innerText) <= 20) {
                $(arr[i])[0].bgColor = 'yellow';
            }
            else if (parseInt(arr[i].innerText) > 20) {
                $(arr[i])[0].bgColor = 'red';
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: i dont know how to use a fiddle link. what shld i do after clicking it. i dont see any code . may not getting loaded

Comment: yes sure .. but im new to this blog .. today only i joined and posted my question . if u say how to put upvote il surely do it :)

Comment: there is two arrow head symbols in leftmost of my answer. just click up arrow. as simple.